# CodePipeline - S3 bucket name is not DNS-compliant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I am using a folder in S3 bucket as the trigger to my code pipeline. Without folder with just bucket name everything works fine, but with folder it throws bucket name is not DNS compliant.

I tried to give below mentioned names:

```
s3://sales/north/
or 
sales/north/
```

Does it look for only bucket name and a folder inside bucket can not be used ? Or the format in which I am proving the bucket name (with folder) is incorrect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, specific to CodePipeline. So we don't need to provide the nested bucket name containing the folder name instead:

1. Ensure you have provided the Bucket Name and not the Bucket ARN.
2. Along with it provide object key so in this case it would be folder name + file name inside that folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Mention only bucketname.. not need to add path**

Additional info :-

ADD a DNS-compliant name to your bucket.

The bucket name must:

> Be unique across all of Amazon S3.
>
> Be between 3 and 63 characters long.
>
> Not contain uppercase characters.
>
> Start with a lowercase letter or number.
>
> Not contain any "." in between.

Comment: my bucket name is unique, in question description i have given just a name. Question is how to provide the folder name along with bucket name if not with "/"

Comment: I have written on first line (mention only bucket name) same thing.. that use only bucketname.. dont use path ..path means it includes '/' in that and that is written in BOLD